# Open new page outside masterdetailpage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I just new to Xamarin.Form with Prism. I want to load the page in different behavior. The first one I achieve already is in image below.

[image: First image]
But I want to do a behavior like below image. Load a new page outside master detail page. How can I do it in prism?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain it a bit further? It's hard to tell what you mean based on the images. Also; please post the relevant code/xaml.

Comment: I have a feeling he's asking about how not to replace a mainpage, but just push a new page.. oh well.

Comment: typo i mean master page instead of mainpage.. :P

Comment: I don't know the implementation specifics for the framework you're using, but as a generic answer for Android, you want to create a new activity. Creating (and launching) a new activity allows you to choose whatever layout you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have figured out how to display the "Hamburger" icon as well as title by doing the following.

> NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterPage/NavigationPage/DetailsPage")

If a user makes a selection from the actions listed on the master page. For Example, let's say settings.

You have a couple of options here, you can do navigate relatively

> NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Settings")

This will navigate to the settings page. This will also display the back button as the second image. Your current page path will be

> MasterPage/NavigationPage/DetailsPage/Settings

Now let's say you want the settings page to be the top details page. You have to navigate to it via an absolute path.

> MasterPage/NavigationPage/Settings
>
> NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterPage/NavigationPage/Settings")

Comment: the third one is not good at all. When I click the back button it back to details page not MasterPage and it animation is not like in my second image. What can I do more?

Comment: I got it. 
 
   
 NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/DetailsPage/SettingPage")

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new page to the stack, page over existing one. To do that you should do navigation like this:

> navigationService.NavigateAsync("Settings")